# regex to find start of word and next word

Tags: regex, perl

Need to find every instance of a phrase that has the word FOO and has BAR some time after but on the same line.

It is formatted like: `[asdf_123/FOO_sdfsdsadasff.x] BAR 123`

Answer (score 1):

A simple

```
FOO.*BAR
```

will probably do

Update after language turned out to be perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<DATA>)  {
    print  if $_ =~ /FOO.*BAR/;
}

__DATA__
[asdf_123/FOO_sdfsdsadasff.x] BAR 123
illegal string
FOO without
without BAR
```

output:

```
[asdf_123/FOO_sdfsdsadasff.x] BAR 123
```

Comment: Nice and simple: That will also find `FOOBAR`. If the user insists there should be at least one character separating the words, then it should be `FOO.+BAR`

Answer (score 0):

How about `FOO.*BAR`; does that work?

Answer (score 0):

```
.*FOO.*BAR.*
```

should work fine.

Comment: One thing to watch out for, here, though.  The leading `.*` makes this less efficient.  The regex engine will run all the way to the end of the line first (due to the greedy match), and then backtrack until it finds the first `F`, then look for an `O`, etc.  Drop the first `.*` and it examines the string from the beginning, until it finds "FOO".  You still take the "greedy match" hit on the `.*` before "BAR", but there's not a lot that can be done about that.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little ambiguous about what constitutes a 'phrase'
but here could be one way to do it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @samples = (
 'asdf_123/FOO_sdfsdsadasff.x BAR 123',
 'FOOBAR BARFOO /ssBARaa',
 'asdf FOOkkBAR zzFOO BAR',
);

for (@samples)
{
    my @phrases = / (\S*FOO\S*)\s (?=.*BAR) /xg;
    print "'$_'\n" for @phrases;
}

__END__
```

Output:

'asdf_123/FOO_sdfsdsadasff.x'
'FOOBAR'
'BARFOO'
'FOOkkBAR'
'zzFOO'